# Performance testing java application that includes webdav protocol

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, stress-testing

I am trying to test a java application which has webdav integrated in it.
The application does some preprocessing and uploads the data on server and i would like to test this complete workflow including the data transfer speed by Webdav.

I am trying to test the performance of this application using JMeter but there seems to be no help on how this can be done.

Does anyone know whether this is possible using JMeter or is there any other free tool to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a free performance testing tool which fully supports all WebDAV methods  you can try out [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/). See [WEBDAV related features](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/features.html#webdav-related-features) documentation bit.

If you just need to upload file you can do it using JMeter as follows:

1. Add [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Sampler to your test plan. Configure it as follows:

   - Method: `PUT`
   - Send Files With the Request

     - Full path to file for upload
     - Provide correct MIME type
2. If your WebDAV server requires authentication add [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) as a child of the HTTP Request
3. Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to check request/response details.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Really appreciate your detailed answer I will look into it immediately. thanks again